# Running Sum with Non-Zero Start Value in Excel Pivot Table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to have a running sum on a pivot table begin at a non zero value? I have a column that is a list of balance changes, and would like to be able to specify a starting balance (i.e. without using dummy transactions at the beginning of the source data). Thanks!

Data:

```
Date         Transaction amount    Account                 
XX/XX/XXX1   -200                  ABC
XX/XX/XXX1   100                   DEF
XX/XX/XXX2   700                   ABC
```

Ideal Pivot Table (with all accounts starting with 300)

```
             Account Balances
Date         ABC        DEF             
XX/XX/XXX1   100        400 
XX/XX/XXX2   800        400
```

Unfortunately adding a running sum column to the original table is not an option as there is no guarantee of order (or possibility to sort).

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I would consider using formulas rather than a pivot table to get your data in the shape you want. Since you are doing a cumulative sum, I cannot imagine you would ever sort these results.

Comment: A running sum column just needs `sumifs()` and the proper anchoring of the sum/criteria ranges. So edit your post further clarify why that is not an option.

Comment: Unless account balances start at -0- you WILL need beginning balance rows. I wouldn't call these "dummies" as they are an essential part of your data to come up with the correct analysis. You might be able to put these in a separate table and use a data model to append them to your transaction data.